# What is up with F-Script? Does swift replace it feature-wise, or only because of marketing?

Tags: macos, f-script

I tried to find recent discussion of F-Script but couldn't. Is it dead because of Swift? SHOULD it be dead because of Swift or have the developers simply moved on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure if it ever went into production or used in real situations. There was/is AppleScript that seems to do about the same as F-Script was trying. For real programming we indeed have moved on from Objective C to Swift.